# Is there any way to access display settings from the menu bar in Mavericks?

Tags: macos, menu-bar

I used to always have an icon, but now it's gone unless mirroring is available :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download the Display Menu app from the [App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/display-menu/id549083868?mt=12)

I use it all the time. Best of all - it is free!